# API Mobile Services time-out on cuncurrent access

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have an API on mobile services that is responsible for user login, i.e, it accepts the username and password, checks if the user exists and replies with a token with some other details.

The problem is, when a client application is running and two different clients call this API at the same time, it returns a time-out for one client, while the other client gets the reply of the other client.

Here is the code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var iterations = 1000;
var bytes = 32;   
var masterKey = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
var _request;
var _response;


exports.post = function(request, response) {
        var username = request.body.username;
        var pass = request.body.password;
       _request = request;
    _response = response
        //_request.respond(400,"Usuário não encontrado.");
        validateUserNamePassword(username, pass)      

}   

function validateUserNamePassword(username, pass){

    var accounts = _request.service.tables.getTable('contaserv');

    accounts
        .where({ username : username , password : pass})
        .read({
            success: function(results) 
            {
                if (results.length === 0) 
                {                                          
                   _request.respond(200, {
                                id: -1,
                                userName: "-1",
                                token: "-1"                       
                    })
                }
                else 
                   {
                        var account = results[0];                       
                            var buff = new Date();
                            var expiry = buff.getTime() + 60 * 60000;
                            var Id = account.id;     
                            var user = account.username;                             
                            _request.respond(200, {
                                id: Id,
                                userName: user,
                                token: zumoJwt(expiry, user, Id, masterKey)                             
                    });

                    }
                },  
                error: function(err) {
                        console.warn(err);
                        _request.respond(401, "Problema ao realizar login");
                }   

            });
}
```

Could the problem be related to the mobile service plan or the database (also hosted on Azure, both free plans)? Could it be something related to  concurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way you are sharing the request and response objects (i.e. using module level variables called _request and _response). The second request is replacing the value, so the response for both requests is being returned to the second request.

The appropriate way to solve this issue is to use scoping to allow access to the objects:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var iterations = 1000;
var bytes = 32;   
var masterKey = "XXXXXXXX";

exports.post = function(request, response) {
    var username = request.body.username;
    var pass = request.body.password;
    validateUserNamePassword(username, pass)      

    function validateUserNamePassword(username, pass){
        var accounts = request.service.tables.getTable('contaserv');

        accounts
            .where({ username : username , password : pass})
            .read({
                success: function(results) {
                    if (results.length === 0) {                                          
                       request.respond(200, {
                            id: -1,
                            userName: "-1",
                            token: "-1"                       
                        });
                    } else {
                        var account = results[0];                       
                        var buff = new Date();
                        var expiry = buff.getTime() + 60 * 60000;
                        var Id = account.id;     
                        var user = account.username;

                        request.respond(200, {
                            id: Id,
                            userName: user,
                            token: zumoJwt(expiry, user, Id, masterKey)                             
                        });
                    }
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    console.warn(err);
                    request.respond(401, "Problema ao realizar login");
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Notice how the validateUserNamePassword function has been moved within the exports.post function so it has access to the request and response objects. If you need to reuse this function elsewhere, you must pass the request and response objects as parameters to the function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for my english, it is my first time asking here. I regenerated the master key.  Thanks Simon and Dale. I will see if it works now.